# What are the ways to execute the code in turn for each category of data in R

Tags: r

Suppose there is any code,and no matter how simple and complex it is, it is important that it works with data where there is some kind of `grouping variable`.
So as reproducible example we can see `iris` dataset. `iris$Species` has three category(setosa,virginic,versicol). Suppose i want simple action - correlation between metric variables for each `species` separately.I can do

```
dt=iris[species==virginic] `(data.table)`
```

and then perform `cor`.
But let's imagine such a situation where the code is complex, huge (it doesn't even make sense to lay it out as an example) and there are many categories in the grouping variable(`groupvar`).

What are the ways that it works in turn for each category, i.e. first, the code is processed for groupware=1, after processing, it starts processing rows that belong to groupware=2, and so on for all categories that are in groupware, until everything passes.

on the example of the same irises

```
[1]setosa
some calculation code.., 
[2] virginic 
some calculation code.., ,
[3] versicol
some calculation code..,
```

Because if there are thousands of categories, I can't set a filter for each one manually.
What can be done to make the code work on all categories of the grouping variable separately?
Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly

```r
# tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  group_split(Species) %>% 
  map(~cor(select(.x, where(is.numeric))))
#> [[1]]
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.7425467    0.2671758   0.2780984
#> Sepal.Width     0.7425467   1.0000000    0.1777000   0.2327520
#> Petal.Length    0.2671758   0.1777000    1.0000000   0.3316300
#> Petal.Width     0.2780984   0.2327520    0.3316300   1.0000000
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.5259107    0.7540490   0.5464611
#> Sepal.Width     0.5259107   1.0000000    0.5605221   0.6639987
#> Petal.Length    0.7540490   0.5605221    1.0000000   0.7866681
#> Petal.Width     0.5464611   0.6639987    0.7866681   1.0000000
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.4572278    0.8642247   0.2811077
#> Sepal.Width     0.4572278   1.0000000    0.4010446   0.5377280
#> Petal.Length    0.8642247   0.4010446    1.0000000   0.3221082
#> Petal.Width     0.2811077   0.5377280    0.3221082   1.0000000

# base
COLS <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)
l <- split(iris, iris$Species)
lapply(l, function(x) cor(x[COLS]))
#> $setosa
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.7425467    0.2671758   0.2780984
#> Sepal.Width     0.7425467   1.0000000    0.1777000   0.2327520
#> Petal.Length    0.2671758   0.1777000    1.0000000   0.3316300
#> Petal.Width     0.2780984   0.2327520    0.3316300   1.0000000
#> 
#> $versicolor
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.5259107    0.7540490   0.5464611
#> Sepal.Width     0.5259107   1.0000000    0.5605221   0.6639987
#> Petal.Length    0.7540490   0.5605221    1.0000000   0.7866681
#> Petal.Width     0.5464611   0.6639987    0.7866681   1.0000000
#> 
#> $virginica
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.4572278    0.8642247   0.2811077
#> Sepal.Width     0.4572278   1.0000000    0.4010446   0.5377280
#> Petal.Length    0.8642247   0.4010446    1.0000000   0.3221082
#> Petal.Width     0.2811077   0.5377280    0.3221082   1.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: hi, i just provided simple example.
Well if code very difficult, suppose like this https://petolau.github.io/Ensemble-of-trees-for-forecasting-time-series/ , very complex and huge code example of tiem series. How this code split for groups.